# Calculating Mercator d3 scaling to match Leaflet zoom level

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, map-projections, mercator

Given a Leaflet zoom level (0..22), how would I calculate D3 scaling value for geoMercator projection?  At zoom=0, the whole world fits within a single tile (256x256). In tiles, the world size is 2^zoom x 2^zoom tiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For comparison with d3 scales for Mercator maps:

A mercator map uses this formula:

```
var point =  [x, Math.log(Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + y / 2))];
```

The scale factor in a d3 map essentially applies the following transform:

```
   point[0] =  point[0] * k;
   point[1] =  -point[1] * k;
```

The default map scale for d3 mercator projections is 961/2π, or 961 pixels by 360 degrees.

One of the quirks of the Mercator formula is that the a square view of the "whole" world will actually cap out at ±85.05113 degrees North/South. Web Mercators can push this as they are not conformal projections. Leaflet pushes the extent of the "whole" world to ±89.15 degrees or so North/South.

So, d3 using a proper Mercator and Leaflet using a web mercator means that scale values might not mesh nicely. This answer on [GIS.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120616/mercator-vs-web-mercator-for-large-scale-topographic-maps) will provide more info on discrepencies between the two.

But, you can still align the two (most of the time).

---

One method, as noted by Yurik in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612175/calculating-mercator-d3-scaling-to-match-leaflet-zoom-level/44621135#comment76228212_44621135) below is to use the zoom level and tile size to get a scale factor:

Web map services use a tiled grid where increasing a zoom level quadruples the number of tiles shown. At zoom level one, the world fits in one tile, at zoom level two, the world fits in four square tiles. The general formula for the number of tiles is then:

Number of Tiles = 4^zoomLevel

Most importantly, each time we zoom in, the number of tiles that it takes to go across the map (one row) doubles.

With this as a starting point, we can figure out how to match the two.

A d3 geoMercator uses `961/(2*Math.PI)` as the default scale - this spreads the equator's 360 degrees (or 2 radians) over 961 pixels. To set this to work for a tile based layer, we only need to know the tile size and the zoom level.

We need to know how many pixels the equator is spread over, to get that we use:

`tileSize * Math.pow(2,zoomLevel)`

This gives us the width of all the tiles that circle the equator. Then we can divide that by 2Pi and get our d3 scale:

`projection.scale(tileSize * Math.pow(2,zoomLevel) / (2 * Math.PI))`

With the differences between a d3 Mercator and a web mercator, there may be issues of distortion depending on where you are located and how far in you zoom, but this should offer good alignment in most situations.

---

Alternatively, we can use the actual corners of the leaflet map to determine an appropriate scale:

D3 features a method that allows a projection to fit a geographic extent to a svg extent: `projection.fitExtent()`. This method takes geojson or geometries. In this answer I'm using geojson.

`.getBounds()` will return the leaftlet map extent, so you can create a geojson bounding box fairly easily:

```
var bbox = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat], 
            [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lat], 
            [mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lng, mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lat], 
            [mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat],
            [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat]
        ]
    ]
}
```

*Note that winding order is actually important in d3 - outer rings are counter clockwise*

Then all you have to do is set your projection to fit that extent:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
   .fitSize([600, 400], bbox);
```

Using a slightly modified [leaflet example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html) (changed centering point and zoom), the whole thing looks like this:

```js
 var features = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -0.17565250396728513,
              51.510118018740904
            ],
            [
              -0.17586708068847653,
              51.509744084227556
            ],
            [
              -0.17584562301635742,
              51.50871574849058
            ],
            [
              -0.17359256744384766,
              51.50613812964363
            ],
            [
              -0.17204761505126953,
              51.50552375337273
            ],
            [
              -0.16966581344604492,
              51.50481587478995
            ],
            [
              -0.16599655151367188,
              51.50454874793857
            ],
            [
              -0.1624774932861328,
              51.504001132997686
            ],
            [
              -0.16058921813964844,
              51.5039744199054
            ],
            [
              -0.16033172607421875,
              51.50426826305929
            ],
            [
              -0.16013860702514648,
              51.5043884710761
            ],
            [
              -0.16016006469726562,
              51.50465559886706
            ],
            [
              -0.15996694564819336,
              51.50510971251776
            ],
            [
              -0.16282081604003906,
              51.505737450406535
            ],
            [
              -0.16466617584228516,
              51.5058710105437
            ],
            [
              -0.16835689544677734,
              51.50588436653591
            ],
            [
              -0.1705455780029297,
              51.506098061878475
            ],
            [
              -0.17273426055908203,
              51.506672363145654
            ],
            [
              -0.17282009124755857,
              51.50681927626061
            ],
            [
              -0.17468690872192383,
              51.508729103648925
            ],
            [
              -0.17511606216430664,
              51.50999782583918
            ],
            [
              -0.17526626586914062,
              51.510144728231545
            ],
            [
              -0.17565250396728513,
              51.510118018740904
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};



 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.5, -0.171], 14);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
 }).addTo(mymap);
 

 var svg = d3.select('#mapid')
   .append('svg')
   .attr('width',600)
   .attr('height',400);

 
 
 
 // Create a geojson bounding box:
 var bbox = {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
   [
    [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat], 
    [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lat], 
    [mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lng, mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lat], 
    [mymap.getBounds()._southWest.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat],
       [mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lng, mymap.getBounds()._northEast.lat]
   ]
  ]
    }
 
 
 var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .fitSize([600, 400], bbox);
 
 var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
 
 svg.append("path")
   .datum(features)
   .attr('d',path);
```

```css
  svg {
   z-index: 10000;
   position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg==" crossorigin=""></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.js"></script>
```

*I have not added the code to update the projection when the map changes, but this is simply recalculating the bounding box and re-applying the fitSize method.*

Comment: thank you for an amazing reply!!!  I arrived at this formula myself, but it seems it might not be 100% correct (even though I did try it and it seems to be matching almost perfectly, so there must be something I'm missing:   `256 * Math.pow(2, zoom) / 2 / Math.PI`

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I posted I figured that the zoom level and the scale might be able to be linked nicely - after all doubling the scale quadruples the size of the map, same as zoom level. However, given the non-conforming nature of the web mercator, the bbox approach *might* offer a closer fit, but, areas near the poles or small scales/zoom levels may still cause grief either way.

Comment: Andrew, if the formula works, do you mind adding it at the beginning, just so that if anyone looks for a simple way, they can use it?

Comment: @Yurik, my bad, I missed this comment, have updated the answer with an explanation of this method as well.