# D3 Map projection scale level corresponding to Zoom level in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, d3.js

Is there any corresponding projection.scale() values in d3 respective to the zoom levels in google map.I think there is 20 levels of zoom in google maps.

Currently I am providng zoom to my d3 Map as below,

```
 projection.scale(zoomLevel);
```

To match the exact zoom level of google map I need the "zoomLevel" value respective to d3.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621135/7106086) is the same question, but with leaflet, the first described approach will work in this case, combining tile size with zoom level to get a d3 scale.